# How to wrap a jQuery control as an angular directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to use this tagging UI control in an Angular app

https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

Without Angular, you would simply initialize

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myTags").tagit();
    });
</script>
```

which would turn any ordered list named myTags into interactive tag

```
<ul id="myTags">
    <li>Tag1</li>
    <li>Tag2</li>
</ul>
```

Here's a small screeshot
http://screencast.com/t/vWng1BgUc1M7

The question is - how do I wrap that to work with angular? I need the  block be inside a partial view. This means that it is not available to the jQuery initialization routine, and thus does not work.

I have a number of jQuery controls I need to wrap, I'd like to understand the best way to handle them. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you're referencing JQuery in a script tag *before* you're referencing Angular, it should be as simple as:

```
app.directive('tagIt', function (){
   return function(scope, elem) {
      elem.tagit();
   }
});
```

Then:

```
<ul id="myTags" tag-it> ... </ul>
```

Comment: We need to set also transclusion, don't we?

Comment: Not in this cause, no. It appears the JS plugin is simply applied to an element.

Comment: On the elem.tagit() line, I get the error TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tagit' - tagit() is a method of $. and does not appear to be available off of elem. ?

Comment: my bad - using an old version of jquery that was incompatible with ng.

Comment: how ez to get it databinding too? or is that a new question?